# Start SymmetricDs with TomEE Plume

Tags: symmetricds

Hello i have two deployment War in my TomEE Plume but there is not running aparently and i dont have any idea why that is happen.

Master configuration .properties:

```
engine.name=corp-000

# The class name for the JDBC Driver

db.driver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver

# The JDBC URL used to connect to the database
db.url=jdbc:jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/db1

# The user to login as who can create and update tables
db.user=sa

# The password for the user to login as
db.password=

registration.url=
sync.url=http://localhost:8080/symmetricNodoPadre/corp-000/sync

# Do not change these for running the demo
group.id=corp
external.id=000

# Don't muddy the waters with purge logging
job.purge.period.time.ms=7200000

# This is how often the routing job will be run in milliseconds
job.routing.period.time.ms=5000
# This is how often the push job will be run.
job.push.period.time.ms=10000
# This is how often the pull job will be run.
job.pull.period.time.ms=10000
# Kick off initial load
initial.load.create.first=true
```

My slave configuration .properties

```
engine.name=$(hostName)

# The class name for the JDBC Driver

db.driver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver

# The JDBC URL used to connect to the database
db.url=jdbc:jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9002/db2

# The user to login as who can create and update tables
db.user=sa

# The password for the user to login as
db.password=

# The HTTP URL of the root node to contact for registration
registration.url=http://localhost:8080/symmetricNodoPadre/corp-000/sync

# Do not change these for running --the demo
group.id=store
external.id=$(hostName)

# This is how often the routing job will be run in milliseconds
job.routing.period.time.ms=5000
# This is how often the push job will be run.
job.push.period.time.ms=10000
# This is how often the pull job will be run.
job.pull.period.time.ms=10000
```

And The web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>SymmetricDS</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>autoStart</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>    

    <!-- To turn on multi server mode in a war deployment uncomment this.  The engines directory
         is controlled by -Dsymmetric.engines.dir=/path/to/dir.  The default value is "engines" 
    <context-param>
        <param-name>multiServerMode</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    -->

     <!-- To specify the name of the properties file to use in a war deployment uncomment this. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>singleServerPropertiesFile</param-name>
        <param-value>/symmetricNodoPadre/WEB-INF/classes/symmetric.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>


     <!-- In order to use extension points defined in an existing spring context turn this setting on    
    <context-param>
       <param-name>useWebApplicationContext</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
   </context-param>
   --> 

    <context-param>
        <param-name>deploymentType</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>
         org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
   </context-param>

   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>org.jumpmind.symmetric.web.rest</param-value>
   </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jumpmind.symmetric.web.SymmetricContextListener</listener-class>        
    </listener>

   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>    

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SymmetricServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jumpmind.symmetric.web.SymmetricServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>        
    </servlet>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
         <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
         </param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>org.jumpmind.symmetric.web.rest</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SymmetricServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/sync/*</url-pattern>        
    </servlet-mapping>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>    


</web-app>
```

Obviusly in the slave Web.xml i put the other path that means symmetricNodoHijo/WEB-INF/classes/symmetric.properties

Comment: Are there any exceptions, errors or warning in the logs?

Comment: No, there is no warnings or errors in the logs, the server say that everything is okey

Comment: are there any logs that start with org.jumpmind ?

Comment: Not, there are only Infos messages but not loss or exceptions or errors

Comment: I was thinking log messages from symmetricds that start with org.jumpmind

Comment: Emmm not in ther symmetricds log dont see anything, because the server dont run, and when i try to see the files in the tomcat there is error 400....

Comment: what happens when you start the server?

Comment: The server response that the deployment is ok but no more, there no sessions or there not connections that i can see

Comment: can you find the name of symmetricDs war in the logs? can you search for `org.jumpmind` in the logs?

Comment: I can see the name of symmetricDs war in the log when the deployment init, but i can see any instance of org.jumpind in the log

Comment: is there only one log file or maybe `org.jumpmind` is redirected to another file?

Comment: Is only one log file, i dont see anymore

Comment: Have you tried deploying another war file under the same TomEE insurance?

Comment: No, im gonna try, and later say you if run

Comment: I tried with another war deploy and it works...

Comment: Try unzipping the war as a zip archive and compare to the successfully deployed war file as well unzipped if something crucial is missing

Comment: Right in this moment i was seeing that, in the folder of WebApps in Tomcat in the folder unzziping of the war there is no one file, but i cant understand why